# Cypress triggers cy.wait(1000) twice in separate tests

Tags: angular, e2e-testing, cypress

In my Angular Cypress E2E Tests, I have a little messy scenario I want to test: Fill out a registration form (localhost) and send it, then go to the (Fake-)Mailbox and collect the verification email. Since the FakeSMTP needs some time, I want to wait before accessing it.

```
it('should submit the registration', () => {
  cy.visit('https://localhost/register);
  ...
  cy.get('button[type=submit]').should('not.be.disabled').click();
});

// Collect the Mail
it('should collect the registration activation email', () => {

  /**
   * Wait 10 Seconds for E-Mail to arrive
   */
  cy.wait(10000); // --> this fires twice

  cy.visit('https://localhost:5080');
  ...
});
```

Why does `cy.wait(10000)` fires twice? First time in the submit (at the very last thing), the second time when it is actually due in the email collection.

Comment: Have you tried using a `before()` hook like so: `before(() => { cy.wait(10000)  })`

Comment: this seems to run once before the first test? That is not what I wanted, as the E-Mail Check is the second test.

Answer (score 1):

I think Cypress is resetting the second test when it encounters a new domain, see this comment [Change baseUrl during test](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2918#issuecomment-565905334)

> Cypress changes the parent domain to match the baseUrl, in order to avoid issues with navigating on a website that does not match the parent domain. The Cypress product is just not coded to handle changing the baseUrl mid test.

To check it out, this simple test mirrors what happens

```js
describe('changing domains', () => {

  it('goes to example.com', () => {
    cy.visit('http://example.com')
  })

  it('changes to example.net', () => {
    cy.wait(10000)
    cy.visit('http://example.net')
  })
})
```

There's a couple of ways to (potentially) avoid the problem, not sure if either will work for you.

1. Go to the new domain early in the second test with a dummy call,

```js
describe('changing domains', () => {

  it('goes to example.com', () => {
    cy.visit('http://example.com')
  })

  it('changes to example.net', () => {
    cy.visit('http://example.net')
    cy.wait(10000)
    cy.visit('http://example.net')
  })
})
```

2. Wait in the first test,

```js
describe('changing domains', () => {

  it('goes to example.com', () => {
    cy.visit('http://example.com')
    cy.wait(10000)
  })

  it('changes to example.net', () => {
    cy.visit('http://example.net')
  })
})
```

---

The ideal solution would be to drop the FakeSMTP server out of the test and trap the mail send in the same way XHR posts are trapped and stubbed with `cy.route()`, then you would not have to wait the 10s, but I don't see any examples so presume it's not yet possible. Perhaps it will be when the native events arrive.

---

I had a look at this post [Testing an email workflow from end to end with Cypress](https://humble.dev/testing-an-email-workflow-from-end-to-end-with-cypress) which creates a custom command to poll the server until the email turns up, using recursion. It essentially acts like a cypress command retry, so you don't wait an arbitrary time (as @Jboucly says should be avoided) but waits in 300ms increments until the email arrives.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('getLastEmail', email => {
  function requestEmail() {
    return cy
      .request({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:4003/last-email',
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/json',
        },
        qs: {
          email,
        },
        json: true,
      })
      .then(({ body }) => {
        if (body) {
          return body;
        }

        // If body is null, it means that no email was fetched for this address.
        // We call requestEmail recursively until an email is fetched.
        // We also wait for 300ms between each call to avoid spamming our server with requests
        cy.wait(300);

        return requestEmail();
      });
  }

  return requestEmail();
});
```

It should really have a recursion-depth limit, in case things don't go as expected and the email never arrives.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```
cy.visit('http=//localhost:5080').wait(10000);
```

A `cy.wait ()` alone is not highly recommended by cypress see [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Having-tests-rely-on-the-state-of-previous-tests)

In the [doc](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Visiting-external-sites), to respect good practice (if possible with your mail utilities) is to use its API to retrieve mails and not to do it via the interface